# how can i change activity to other activity when i click list items in array custom adapter

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile-application

how can i change this activity to other activity when i clik on list items.
In my Android application, I have two activity classes. I have a custom list view and  on the first item clicked   show the second activity:
what i write in onitemcliklisten
**here is my FragmentList.java  file **
thanks

```
FragmentList.java
package com.kbhtech.sharedpreferencedemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FragmentList extends Fragment   {

    private String getActivity;

    public static FragmentList newInstance() {
        FragmentList fragment = new FragmentList();

        return fragment;
    }
    public FragmentList() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    Context activity;

    ListView postsListView;
    PostsListAdapter postsListAdapter;
    ArrayList<BeanSampleList> postsBeanSampleList =new ArrayList<BeanSampleList>();

    SharedPreference sharedPreference;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        activity = getActivity();
        postsBeanSampleList=new ArrayList<BeanSampleList> (  );
        sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();
        postsBeanSampleList.add( new BeanSampleList( 1, "Chapter 1", "Sec 1-5" ) );
        postsBeanSampleList.add( new BeanSampleList( 2, "Chapter 2", "Sec 6-25A " ) );
        postsBeanSampleList.add( new BeanSampleList( 3, "Chapter 3", "Sec 26-35" ) );
        postsBeanSampleList.add( new BeanSampleList( 4, "Chapter 4", "Moscow" ) );
        postsBeanSampleList.add( new BeanSampleList( 5, "Chapter 5", "Brasília" ) );
        postsBeanSampleList.add( new BeanSampleList( 6, "Chapter 6", "Berlin" ) );
        postsBeanSampleList.add( new BeanSampleList( 7, "Chapter 7", "Paris" ) );
        postsBeanSampleList.add( new BeanSampleList( 8, "Chapter 8", "Dublin" ) );
        postsBeanSampleList.add( new BeanSampleList( 9, "Chapter 9", "Rome" ) );
        postsBeanSampleList.add( new BeanSampleList( 10, "Chapter 10", "Tokyo" ) );

    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container,false);

        postsListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.posts_list);
        postsListAdapter = new PostsListAdapter(activity, postsBeanSampleList);
        postsListView.setAdapter(postsListAdapter);
        postsListView.setAdapter(postsListAdapter);
        postsListView.setAdapter( postsListAdapter );
        postsListView.setOnItemClickListener ( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView <?> adapterView , View view , int i , long l) {

                if (i == 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, Chapter1.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else if (i == 1) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, Chapter2.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
            }
            }
        } );


        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        postsListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }




    public class PostsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context context;
        ArrayList<BeanSampleList> postBeanSampleList;
        SharedPreference sharedPreference;

        public PostsListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<BeanSampleList> postBeanSampleList) {

            this.context = context;
            this.postBeanSampleList = postBeanSampleList;
            sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView txtTitle,txtSubTitle;
            ImageView btnFavourite;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return postBeanSampleList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return postBeanSampleList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_posts_list, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.txtPostTitle);
                holder.txtSubTitle = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.txtPostSubTitle);

                holder.btnFavourite = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.favouritesToggle);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            BeanSampleList beanSampleList = (BeanSampleList) getItem(position);
            holder.txtTitle.setText(beanSampleList.getTitle());
            holder.txtSubTitle.setText(beanSampleList.getSubTitle());


            if (checkFavoriteItem(beanSampleList)) {
                holder.btnFavourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite);
                holder.btnFavourite.setTag("active");
            } else {
                holder.btnFavourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_outline);
                holder.btnFavourite.setTag("deactive");
            }
            holder.btnFavourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {


                    String tag = holder.btnFavourite.getTag().toString();
                    if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("deactive")) {
                        sharedPreference.addFavorite(context, postBeanSampleList.get(position));
                        holder.btnFavourite.setTag("active");
                        holder.btnFavourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite);
                    } else {
                        sharedPreference.removeFavorite(context, postBeanSampleList.get(position));
                        holder.btnFavourite.setTag("deactive");
                        holder.btnFavourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_outline);
                    }
                }
            });
            return convertView;
        }


        public boolean checkFavoriteItem(BeanSampleList checkProduct) {
            boolean check = false;
            List<BeanSampleList> favorites = sharedPreference.loadFavorites(context);
            if (favorites != null) {
                for (BeanSampleList product : favorites) {
                    if (product.equals(checkProduct)) {
                        check = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return check;
        }
    }
}
```

ListActivity.java (MainAct...)

```
package com.kbhtech.sharedpreferencedemo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class ListActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my );
        txtHeader.setText("Posts List");

        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        FragmentList fragmentList = FragmentList.newInstance();

        if (manager.findFragmentByTag("fragment_list") == null) {
            ft.replace(R.id.main_content, fragmentList, "fragment_list").commit();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {


            case R.id.action_favourites:
                Intent i=new Intent(ListActivity.this,FavouriteListActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

FragmentFavourite.java

```
package com.kbhtech.sharedpreferencedemo;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FragmentFavourite extends Fragment  {
    private ListView favouriteListView;
    public static FavouritesListAdapter favouritsListAdapter;
    private ArrayList<BeanSampleList> favouritesBeanSampleList;
    SharedPreference sharedPreference;

    public static FragmentFavourite newInstance() {
        FragmentFavourite fragment = new FragmentFavourite();
        return fragment;

    }
    public FragmentFavourite() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        sharedPreference=new SharedPreference();
        try {
            favouritesBeanSampleList = sharedPreference.loadFavorites(getActivity());
        } catch (NullPointerException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favourite, container, false);
        favouriteListView =(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.favourits_list);
        return  rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.e("onResume", "onResume Called");
        if(favouritesBeanSampleList != null ) {
            try {
                favouritsListAdapter = new FavouritesListAdapter(getActivity(), favouritesBeanSampleList);
                favouriteListView.setAdapter(favouritsListAdapter);
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            favouritsListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public class FavouritesListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        Context context;
        List<BeanSampleList> modellist;
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        ArrayList<BeanSampleList> favouritesBeanSampleList;
        public FavouritesListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<BeanSampleList> favouritesBeanSampleList) {
            this.context = context;
            this.favouritesBeanSampleList = favouritesBeanSampleList;
            this.favouritesBeanSampleList=new ArrayList <BeanSampleList> (  );
            this.modellist= favouritesBeanSampleList;
            inflater=LayoutInflater.from ( context );

        }


        public int getCount() {

            return favouritesBeanSampleList.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return favouritesBeanSampleList.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }





        class ViewHolder {
            TextView txtTitle,txtSubTitle;
            ImageView btnFavourite;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {

            final ViewHolder holder;
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_favourites_list, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtFavtitle);
                holder.txtSubTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtFavSubTitle);
                BeanSampleList  selectfavouritesBeanSampleList =favouritesBeanSampleList.get( position );
                holder.btnFavourite = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.favouritesToggleImg);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.txtTitle.setText(favouritesBeanSampleList.get(position).getTitle());
            holder.txtSubTitle.setText(favouritesBeanSampleList.get(position).getSubTitle());
            holder.btnFavourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite);

            holder.btnFavourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    sharedPreference.removeFavorite(context, favouritesBeanSampleList.get(position));
                    favouritesBeanSampleList.remove(favouritesBeanSampleList.get(position));
                    holder.btnFavourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_outline);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            });

            convertView.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {


                }
            } );


            return convertView;
        }
    }

}
```

Chapter 1 class

```
package com.kbhtech.crpc4jse;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Chapter1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView ( R.layout.activity_chapter1 );
    }
}
```

**activity_chapter1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Chapter1">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtch1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Chapter 1"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtch1s1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="प्रारंभिक( preliminary)"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtch1s2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Sec 1-5 " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtch1d1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:textSize="23sp"
                android:text="@string/chapter" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yes sir, and also learn  how it works

Comment: Put this into your onItemClick(...) - Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), <SecondActivity>.class); getActivity().startActivity(intent);

Comment: Please send it in coding.. and also set it in my code please

Comment: And first raw go to chapter1.claas

Comment: Can i use switch method? Nut i dont how to coding it.. explain it please

Comment: Reply please sir , .. thanks

Comment: package com.kbhtech.crpc4jse;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Chapter1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView ( R.layout.activity_chapter1 );
    }
}

Comment: i edit my post again.. now check my chapter 1 class and its xml file also.. tell me what i missed in chapter 1 class ?? please reply in code style pls what i wrote in chapter 1 class

Comment: Reply please Sir